# How do I create mandatory fields in my data entry form for google sheet app script button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

I have created a data entry form on google sheets that has a submit button that triggers a script. I want to ensure that all fields are not blank when someone submits the form through the script. I want the script to check if any of the fields `(C5, C7, C9, C11, C13)` are blank and return a `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert` rejecting the submission as follows:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please enter all mandatory fields.');
```

Can someone please assist? :)

Below is the function's code:

```
//Data Sheet
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("OrderInput"); 
   
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C13").getValue()]];

  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 5).setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Request successfully submitted!');
formSS.getRange("C5").clear()
formSS.getRange("C7").clear()
formSS.getRange("C9").clear()
formSS.getRange("C11").clear()
formSS.getRange("C13").clear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can add a `for` loop to check each entry in `values`, set a flag to true when a blank is found, then break away from the loop:

**Sample Code:**

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("OrderInput"); 
   
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C13").getValue()]];

  //Check Blank Values
  for (i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    if (values[0][i] == '') {
      var blankExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (blankExists) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please enter all mandatory fields.');
  }
  else {
    datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 5).setValues(values);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Request successfully submitted!');
    formSS.getRange("C5").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C7").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C9").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C11").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C13").clear();
  }
}
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]